# How can I stop spam email of "thanks for checking in", but allow tweet email?

Tags: twitter

When I log into Twitter, which I do from time to time though not often, it says "thanks for checking in"—I want to stop that.

But I still want to be emailed if I am sent a DM or tweeted. I get those rarely (if at all), as I don't have much personal comms with people.

I just want to stop the "thanks for checking in" email.

Comment: @pnuts re your edit. re the title. Isn't it useful to have 'twitter' in the title, so people see in the title what web app I am talking about? Tags are useful for searches but aren't  a substitute for a good title(so having a twitter tag is of course important, but it doesn't remove the usefulness of twitter in the title). Also, 'suspend' isn't really a good term for stopping an unwanted email.When people search for a problem like this they'd likely search for stop spam(rather than suspend).Spam being unwanted/unsolicited email.A message thanking you for logging in,is a good candidate for spam

Comment: @pnuts re your comment about an unsubscribe option.  To test it i'd have to know when the 'thank you for checking in' email would arrive and have people tweeting me and I don't have that and it'd take time to test so I was hoping somebody would've had the issue and spotted what was happening naturally. i'd want to know that it's not doing more or less, and that it works.

Comment: @pnuts either that or if it's clear enough what 'opt out' is doing and one can give it the benefit of the doubt. I believe that is sufficiently the case here, with my answer.

Comment: @pnuts and why did you replace "into" with "in to"? "into" is a word.. I know some people say 'alot' and that's not a word, but into is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the Email there is an 'opt-out' option and an 'email settings' option.

[image]

The email settings option has everything ticked.  Obviously I don't need everything ticked but a question one could ask is, what corresponds to the 'thank you for checking in' message.

If you click 'Email Settings'

There are many options all ticked, and a bunch below them all ticked. Here is that lower bunch.
[image]

If within the email you click 'opt out'

Then the email notifications list gets updated.

[image]

Notice "Tips on getting more out of twitter" becomes unticked.

So, it's most likely that option is the one that controls whether receiving that email.

That said, i'm going to have these ones ticked/unticked and see how it goes.
[image]

Comment: @pnuts Oh it's an answer alright. Just saying 'opt out' would've been problematic. Any test would be to see whether it worked and if it did more or if it did less. But, since the opt out option brought me to email notifications and amends them(and my answer shows that), I can see it's not going to opt me out of much, and it's most likely I won't get those 'check in' emails anymore. But I will of course update here to report if I do start getting them again.. that'd be a case of opt out not working. Or if I can't get tweets(if I notice), but that's most unlikely as tweets is ticked.

Comment: @pnuts As for filters. A long while back I had just Yahoo and Yahoo instant messenger - the latter to notify me when getting emails. I wanted to filter emails and for such filtered emails to not trigger the notifier. Unfortunately that wasn't possible. I filtered them into a folder but still got alerted with a sound for each email. Nowadays I don't get notifications (bing sound) for any email.. I could use a filter but filters aren't as wonderful as i'd like.

Comment: @pnuts And re the first sentence of your first comment "I see what you mean! "  you refer to the first paragraph i've sinced removed it, because the system turned out to be not so ambiguous.